# how to load incremental data into another cassandra node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My goal is to sync 2 separate Cassandra nodes weekly(based on scheduling). The question:

1. I'll take a snapshot and transfer the snapshot files and copy it in the another Cassandra table node.
2. I had enabled incremental_backup=true so next time I want to sync only the updated values into other Cassandra node. So Is there any way to do this? and What are the major things to be considered when taking a backup?

what I'm doing 
table->snapshot->snapshot_name-> scp all the files -> another cassandra server table->nodetool refresh -> giving me all the data

table->backup->scp all the files-> another cassandra server table->nodetool refresh -> throughs me the error

```
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Comment: Wait, is this about taking backups or having two nodes in sync? Cassandra has built-in synchronisation of nodes in a ring.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak It's about taking syncing two Cassandra separate servers. Since We use Incremental_backup enabled using sstableloader it only syncs table content, not the backup folder data which has updations.Suppose say in step1:I had taken the snapshot of some 10million rows and copied snapshot to another cassandra node. step2: some 1 million rows are newly added want to sync only this 1 million rows into another cassandra node.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. Do you want to backup one server and restore from that backup on another?

Comment: Why `2 separate` is added in question? Are nodes in separate clusters?

Comment: Could you check system.log on another cassandra server table? Could you try https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html sstableloader?

Comment: Ok.. Let me put this way,  I have cassandra cluster1 and cassandra cluster 2.These 2 are completely different setups some of the tables in the cluster 1  has to sync with cluster2 weekly. So for that I'm taking snaphot and copying the snapshot files to the path of the cluster2 tables and doing nodetool refresh.Upto here is fine. But the issue raises when I turn on Incremental_backup=True. So as we know if we do this cassandra creates backup folder inside table folder where its has latest updated data. so I want to sync only that particular data every time (delta). So how can I do this?